# How do I populate the file structure browse tree in windows XP with a specific directory?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I am always saving files to a particular directory and I find that it would save a great deal of time if I could populate the drop down tree in the browse dialog box that comes up when you are saving or loading files from an applications. Is there a way to do this with a registry key or via user interface interaction?

Normally you see the usual My Computer, C Drive, Desktop, D Drive, My network places.  I would like to have a specific directory such as C:\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\ appear in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You could customize your "My Places" bar by changing one of the items to the directory where you commonly save/load files.  There are several articles on the web that explain how to do this just search for: my places bar

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing is application specific and each one could store the folder to start in differently. I don't think that there's one overriding value you can set.

You might get a better response if you asked this question over on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).